# My list becomes crazy after sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm creating a list editor using Angular and jQuery UI. The goal is to add/edit/remove/sort items.

Here's my HTML code to display the list.

```html
<ul id="sortable" >
    <li ng-repeat="cat in admin.catalogues">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="cat.title" />                    
        <label for="image">Image</label><input type="text" name="image" ng-model="cat.image" istype="image" />
        <button ng-click="admin.removeCatalogue(cat)">Remove</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then I have these Angular methods (I have just copied what should be useful).

```js
this.catalogues = [];

this.addCatalogue = function () {
    var newcat = {
        title: "",
        image: "",
        pdf: ""
    };
    this.catalogues.push(newcat);
};

this.removeCatalogue = function (item) {
    this.catalogues.splice(this.catalogues.indexOf(item), 1);
};

this.sort = function(fromIndex, toIndex){
    var element = this.catalogues[fromIndex];
    this.catalogues.splice(fromIndex, 1);
    this.catalogues.splice(toIndex, 0, element);
 };
```

And finally this jQuery script for the sortable part - it works using jQuery UI, and I call the Angular controller to update the list. I have probably found this snippet somewhere on Stackoverflow.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    startIndex = -1;
    newIndex = -1;
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        placeholder:'placeholder',
        start: function (event, ui) {
            startIndex = ($(ui.item).index());
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            newIndex = ($(ui.item).index());
            angular.element(document.getElementById('content')).controller().sort(startIndex, newIndex);
        }
    });
});
```

Adding items, removing and sorting are all working fine. But after sorting, the list becomes crazy. New items are added more or less randomly inside the list, and the remove button sometimes removes more than one item.

I have created a Fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Neow85/jbg8kdv4/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should try to avoid doing angular stuff in jQuery, try using [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) (angular.element(document.getElementById('content')).controller() is a big no-go)

Comment: @MartijnWelker I used the ui-sortable directive. Installed in 2 minutes, almost nothing done, and problem solved. Thanks a lot!